# Как вызвать нужную функцию из DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

Здравствуйте!

Осваиваю работу с `dll`, по вот этому полезному материалу: [Как подключить к своей программе `DLL`-библиотеку](http://www.softtime.ru/cpp/read.php?id_forum=1&id_theme=1459)

Проблема вот какая: Есть несколько методов и все они находятся в `dll`... Как можно вызвать интересующий нас метод? Может к `GetProcAddress` прибавить смещение какое-то?
Спасибо.

Comment: Каких ещё методов? Пример -- в студию!

Comment: Интересующий метод можно вызвать получив указатель на него по его имени (передав его в GetProcAddress), затем полученный указатель преобразовав к необходимому типу функции, и затем произведя вызов функции передав ей необходимые параметры. В статье которую вы указали все написано ведь)))

Comment: @alexlz: слово «метод» позволяет подозревать, что ТС хочет работать с _классом_, описанным в DLL'ке.

Comment: progzdeveloper, а можно простой пример? Просто имя функции в dll и имя указателя на нее в исполняемом файле должны совпадать?

Comment: VladD и с классами, структурами тоже хотелось бы научиться работать.
А где можно прочитать про dll наиболее полно и чтобы для VStudio подходил материал?

Comment: @Alerr: если функция написана и _скомпилирована_ как чистый C — имена должны совпадать, кроме этого, функция должна быть _экспортирована_ (`__declspec(dllexport)`). Почитайте [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx). По поводу работы с классами через границы DLL — старшие товарищи не рекомендуют. (Это всё, конечно, относится к динамической загрузке DLL через `LoadLibrary`.)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

При создании проекта в компиляторе укажите библиотека DLL.
(в visual studio создать->проект->win32(или консоль) -> далее -> **библиотека dll + пустой проект**) далее вставить код

Это код DLL

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void dll_function(int arg);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void dll_function(int arg)
{
std::cout << "\nФункция из DLL: передан аргумент=" << arg;
}
```

Теперь вызов функции из своего проекта.

```
int main()
{
std::system("chcp 1251");

LPWSTR name = L"dll 2.dll"; // загрузка модуля DLL
HINSTANCE le_module = LoadLibrary(name);
if(le_module==NULL){std::cout << "\nбиблиотека не загружена!";}

LPCSTR func_name = "dll_function"; // название загружаемой функции
FARPROC adresse_la_func = GetProcAddress(le_module, func_name);
if(adresse_la_func!=0)
{
std::cout << "\nadresse_la_func=" << adresse_la_func;
typedef void (__cdecl *прототип)(int);
((прототип)adresse_la_func)(5);
}

FreeLibrary(le_module);

std::cout << "\n";
std::system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: C подключением и вызовом функций из dll разобрался, хотя что вот это GetModuleFileName(NULL, (LPTSTR)mod_name, size__); в вашем примере(извлекает путь к исполняемому файлу текущего процесса), что она сделает? Сейчас вопрос возник с листингом DUMPBIN. Содержание листинга не совсем понтно?

Comment: 1)Это ничего, можно убрать.

2) Зачем вам этот листинг? Вы функцию получили? Вот и все что необходимо знать. Остальное уже не относится к вопросу.

Comment: Но а все же, если знаете... Или просто новый вопрос задать?

Answer (score 0):

Продолжил разбираться и наткнулся на программу DUMPBIN, которая:

The Microsoft COFF Binary File Dumper (DUMPBIN.EXE) displays information about Common Object File Format (COFF) binary files. You can use DUMPBIN to examine COFF object files, standard libraries of COFF objects, executable files, and dynamic-link libraries (DLLs).
Это отсюда: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx

Итак, я захотел посмотреть таблицу импорта библиотеки которую сам же и собрал...
Вот что я увидел:
[image]

Где тут таблица импорта? Кроме имени функции, содержащейся в dll ничего не смог разобрать. Сколько переменных и какого типа она принимает, что возвращает функция, если вообще что-то возвращает? На эти вопросы можно по этой картинке ответить?
Что такое Summary, что за цифры? Цифры 0 00011005-это смещение в памяти по которому будет расположен указатель на функцию, по которому вызывается функция?
Что за характеристики и 00000000? И прочие цифры типа 1 ordinal base что означают? Что за порядок?
Расшифруйте кто может)

Спасибо.

Comment: А у вас есть функции с `__declspec(dllexport)`? Они объявлены как `extern "C"`?

Comment: Да, есть:
....
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int HelloWorld(.....)
{
  return 3;
}

Comment: Я не уверен что можно получить прототип функции из DLL. Ведь эта информация хранится обычно в lib файлах. Всё что dll экспортирует, так это идентификатор. Дальше уже вызывающая сторона приводит полученный адрес, по указанному строковому идентификатору, к нужному указателю на функцию.